Prevent Gradle from caching generated Android versionCode
I use the following to auto generate a version code that should always be higher than the last:
android {
   ...
   versionCode generateVersionCode()
   ...
}

def generateVersionCode() {
    println "Generating version code..."
    return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 10000)
}

The problem is that gradle seems to cache this value so it does not get incremented on every time I build/run the project. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour without disabling caching completely?
